# Using a join in Arc with feature classes containing a definition query always return an inner join

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.4

At Arc 10.4, I am attempting to do an outer join (using the "Keep all records" option) between two file geodatabase feature class layer tables.  Each of the two tables has an identical Definition Query applied to it. The join completes without an error statement from Arc.  However, the resulting join is an *inner* join (containing only the matching records), instead of the expected outer join. I conducted an internet search, which did not return anything useful.  Is this a known Arc bug?

Comment: I believe the `Keep all records` option gives you a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` where every record should be returned in the first layer and only matches from the join layer.

Comment: File geodatabase access is not based on a RDBMS engine, so assuming it will behave like it is presents risks. Looking at the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/essentials-of-joining-tables.htm), it does not appear that "Keep all records" was intended to imply an outer join.